# Reorderable list and keys in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to go from ListView to Reorderable List with my simple todo app. I think I need a key somewhere, but not sure where;

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: const TodoApp(),
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
  ));
}

class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}

class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> storedText = [];
  List<bool> checkedValue = [];

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Todo"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 15.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                //
                // LIST STARTS
                //

                child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: storedText.length,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                        newIndex -= 1;
                      }
                      final String item = storedText.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      storedText.insert(newIndex, item);
                    });
                  },
                  //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    //
                    //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
                    //
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.yellow),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          //
                          //LIST TILE STARTS
                          //
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.black,
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                              //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                              title: Text(storedText[index]),
                              value: checkedValue.isNotEmpty
                                  ? checkedValue[index]
                                  : false,
                              onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  checkedValue[index] =
                                      newCheckedValue ?? false;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _textyController,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                      storedText.insert(0, value);
                      checkedValue.insert(0, false);
                      _textyController.clear();
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: '+ Add a task',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    focusColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to add a key in the CheckboxListTile but that didnt work (or maybe I didnt do it correctly? I set the key as "key: ValueKey(storedText)"

I even tried "key: ValueKey(storedText[index])" and that didnt seem to work either.

Comment: Check out this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html

Answer (score 1):

`itemBuilder` widgets need to have `key` on each item.

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return Padding(
    key: Key('$index ${storedText[index]}'),//make sure unique one, you can also use `index`
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
```

Comment: it reorders now, thanks. However, when I check an item off, then move it, the item that replaces it becomes checked, and not the item I originally checked. So it looks like its applying the check to the index position, rather than the key?

Comment: Ah, just writing that, and your help allowed me to figure out that I also need to change the index for the bool as well, not just the string. i.e.

```
final String text = storedText.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      storedText.insert(newIndex, text);

                      final bool checked = checkedValue.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      checkedValue.insert(newIndex, checked);
```

Comment: Creating a model class will be best imo